# libgdx game start freezing after some tim

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My game start freezing after some time (take too much ram), I want to try draw 3( later more) string using loop method. My code is this:

```
    public class Simple implements ApplicationListener {
        private OrthographicCamera camera;
        private SpriteBatch batch;
        private BitmapFont font;
        private GlyphLayout layout;
        String a1 = "aa";
        String a2 = "bb";
        String a3 = "cc";
        int a = 0;

        @Override
        public void create() {
            camera = new OrthographicCamera();
            camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
        }

        @Override
        public void render() {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            camera.update();
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
            batch.begin();
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                layout = new GlyphLayout();
                font = new BitmapFont();
                layout.setText(font, "a" + i);
                font.draw(batch, layout, 200 + (15 * i), 200);
            }
            batch.end();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `layout = new GlyphLayout(); font = new BitmapFont();` you should not create a new font each ~20 miliseconds you draw something.

Comment: Then how to do it , plz giv some code

Comment: move those two lines to `create()` and see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To visualize what EpicPandaForce mentioned in the comments:

```
public class Simple implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private GlyphLayout layout;
    String a1 = "aa";
    String a2 = "bb";
    String a3 = "cc";
    int a = 0;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        //Initialize the fields in create()           
        layout = new GlyphLayout();
        font = new BitmapFont();

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            //Use them like you do.
            layout.setText(font, "a" + i);
            font.draw(batch, layout, 200 + (15 * i), 200);
        }
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is going to work. You are not specifying a bitmapfont anywhere so when you draw it using layout you probably get a `nullPointerException`. In the create method you probably want to initialize font with `font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Path to bitmapfont"));`.

Using new is a expensive operation. The update() method is being called every frame and you are creating new objects each time it is being called. On top of that `BitmapFont()` is not a small object. And each time you create a new object for font and layout the previous object it holded needs to be collected by the garbage collector. A basic rule is to never use the `new` keyword in the `update()` method but rather change it and/or use it like I did just now. To visualize this in a very simple way:

```
Object o; // <-- a simple container
new Object(); // <-- a object stored in memory in all it's glory

Object o = new Object(); // <-- container o is now pointing to the memory address of new Object()

Object o = new Object(); // container 0 is now pointing to a different object in memory
//But the old one is still chilling at it's own address and needs to be collected
```

Comment: New problem occured; now I noted that it did not draw the vale of string a1; but it draw a1 (not "aa") , plz help me

Comment: `layout.setText(font, "a" + i);` will create a string `a1`, `a2`, etc  and you are not able to call variables or methods this way. If you really need that you have to look into reflection. I cannot figure out what you are trying to accomplish here but if you want to draw `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, etc in turn then put this in a array, list or other data structure and loop through that using `i`. I made a pastebin for you ;) http://pastebin.com/ccyT4eCk

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't necessarily that you're creating a new font every render call (though you certainly shouldn't be doing that for performance reasons,) but more that you're not releasing the font from memory via `dispose`.

Normally garbage collection will clean up after you, but in some cases you need to clean up after yourself.  Libgdx utilizes some unmanaged code for performance reasons and so needs you to manually release it.  The doc makes this clear, and expounds upon why.

> The texture for a BitmapFont loaded from a file is managed. dispose()
>   must be called to free the texture when no longer needed. A BitmapFont
>   loaded using a TextureRegion is managed if the region's texture is
>   managed. Disposing the BitmapFont disposes the region's texture, which
>   may not be desirable if the texture is still being used elsewhere.

So call dispose when you're done with the font, and initialize your font in your constructor.  Otherwise your program will use more and more RAM and performance will be terrible.